# How to retrieve The DAO proposals using geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, the-dao, nodejs

I'm using Node.JS with Web3 interface to a Go Geth server.

I'm trying to get proposals in both TESTNET and LIVENET but I'm unable:

What I've done so far:

- I'm using Node.JS
- I've got the .abi defintions for `theDAO`, `theDAOInterface`, `theDAOTokenInterface`, `theDAOToken`, `theDAOManagedAccount` and `theDAOManagedAccountInterface`.

The only interface that implements proposals() function is theDAOInterface. Then with the abi definition I do:

```
var theDAOInterfaceABI = [{ "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "proposals", "outputs": [{ "name": "recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "description", "type": "string" }, { "name": "votingDeadline", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "open", "type": "bool" }, { "name": "proposalPassed", "type": "bool" }, { "name": "proposalHash", "type": "bytes32" }, { "name": "proposalDeposit", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "newCurator", "type": "bool" }, { "name": "yea", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "nay", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "creator", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "rewardAccount", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "daoCreator", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_transactionData", "type": "bytes" }], "name": "executeProposal", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "unblockMe", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "totalRewardToken", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "allowedRecipients", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_to", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "transferWithoutReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_description", "type": "string" }, { "name": "_transactionData", "type": "bytes" }, { "name": "_debatingPeriod", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_newCurator", "type": "bool" }], "name": "newProposal", "outputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "DAOpaidOut", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "minQuorumDivisor", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_newContract", "type": "address" }], "name": "newContract", "outputs": [], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_allowed", "type": "bool" }], "name": "changeAllowedRecipients", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "halveMinQuorum", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "paidOut", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_newCurator", "type": "address" }], "name": "splitDAO", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "DAOrewardAccount", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "proposalDeposit", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "numberOfProposals", "outputs": [{ "name": "_numberOfProposals", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "lastTimeMinQuorumMet", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_toMembers", "type": "bool" }], "name": "retrieveDAOReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "receiveEther", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "getNewDAOAddress", "outputs": [{ "name": "_newDAO", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_supportsProposal", "type": "bool" }], "name": "vote", "outputs": [{ "name": "_voteID", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "getMyReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "rewardToken", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_from", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_to", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "transferFromWithoutReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalDeposit", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "changeProposalDeposit", "outputs": [], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "blocked", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "curator", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_transactionData", "type": "bytes" }], "name": "checkProposalCode", "outputs": [{ "name": "_codeChecksOut", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "recipient", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "newCurator", "type": "bool" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "description", "type": "string" }], "name": "ProposalAdded", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "position", "type": "bool" }, { "indexed": true, "name": "voter", "type": "address" }], "name": "Voted", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "result", "type": "bool" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "quorum", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "ProposalTallied", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "_newCurator", "type": "address" }], "name": "NewCurator", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "_allowed", "type": "bool" }], "name": "AllowedRecipientChanged", "type": "event" }];
var theDAOInterface = web3.eth.contract(theDAOInterfaceABI).at(theDAOAddress);
var proposals = theDAOInterface.proposals()
```

What I've got:

LIVENET:

DAOInterface.proposals():

```
["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0","","0",false,false,"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0",false,"0","0","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
```

DAOInterface.numberOfProposals() returns 0.

TESTNET:

DAOInterface.proposals():

```
["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000,0,,0,false,false,0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,0,false,0,0,0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
```

DAOInterface.numberOfProposals() returns 193.

What's happening with these APIs? Am I the only one trying to work with this stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q**: What's happening with these APIs? Am I the only one trying to work with this staff?

Your code is probably returning the correct results.

There are no proposals for The DAO on Mainnet yet as proposals cannot be created until The DAO's closing time has passed.

From The DAO's [source code](http://etherscan.io/address/0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413#code):

```
function newProposal(
    address _recipient,
    uint _amount,
    string _description,
    bytes _transactionData,
    uint _debatingPeriod,
    bool _newCurator
) onlyTokenholders returns (uint _proposalID) {

    // Sanity check
    if (_newCurator && (
        _amount != 0
        || _transactionData.length != 0
        || _recipient == curator
        || msg.value > 0
        || _debatingPeriod < minSplitDebatePeriod)) {
        throw;
    } else if (
        !_newCurator
        && (!isRecipientAllowed(_recipient) || (_debatingPeriod <  minProposalDebatePeriod))
    ) {
        throw;
    }

    if (_debatingPeriod > 8 weeks)
        throw;

    if (!isFueled
        || now < closingTime
        || (msg.value < proposalDeposit && !_newCurator)) {

        throw;
    }
    ...
```

From checking the variables for The DAO's contract in Ethereum Wallet (Mist)

```
closingTime = 1464426000 // which is Sat, 28 May 2016 09:00:00 GMT
isFueled = true
```

The following statement within `newProposal(...)` prevents proposals being created before the closing time of the crowdfunding period of The DAO, as `now < closingTime` evaluates to *true* since `now` is less than Sat, 28 May 2016 09:00:00 GMT:

```
    if (!isFueled
        || now < closingTime
        || (msg.value < proposalDeposit && !_newCurator)) {

        throw;
    }
```

---

**Q**: What do the items in the proposals array mean?

Here is the Proposal structure - the comments will help explain the fields of each Proposal record in the Proposals array:

```
// A proposal with `newCurator == false` represents a transaction
// to be issued by this DAO
// A proposal with `newCurator == true` represents a DAO split
struct Proposal {
    // The address where the `amount` will go to if the proposal is accepted
    // or if `newCurator` is true, the proposed Curator of
    // the new DAO).
    address recipient;
    // The amount to transfer to `recipient` if the proposal is accepted.
    uint amount;
    // A plain text description of the proposal
    string description;
    // A unix timestamp, denoting the end of the voting period
    uint votingDeadline;
    // True if the proposal's votes have yet to be counted, otherwise False
    bool open;
    // True if quorum has been reached, the votes have been counted, and
    // the majority said yes
    bool proposalPassed;
    // A hash to check validity of a proposal
    bytes32 proposalHash;
    // Deposit in wei the creator added when submitting their proposal. It
    // is taken from the msg.value of a newProposal call.
    uint proposalDeposit;
    // True if this proposal is to assign a new Curator
    bool newCurator;
    // Data needed for splitting the DAO
    SplitData[] splitData;
    // Number of Tokens in favor of the proposal
    uint yea;
    // Number of Tokens opposed to the proposal
    uint nay;
    // Simple mapping to check if a shareholder has voted for it
    mapping (address => bool) votedYes;
    // Simple mapping to check if a shareholder has voted against it
    mapping (address => bool) votedNo;
    // Address of the shareholder who created the proposal
    address creator;
}
```

---

**Q**:  I mean the array I'm getting, the one full of 0x0000, false, and non-sense fields.

Your dummy array result is created by following statement that adds one record to the `proposals` array that the subsequent code does not initialise:

```
proposals.length = 1; // avoids a proposal with ID 0 because it is used
```

in the the `DAO` constructor below:

```
function DAO(
    address _curator,
    DAO_Creator _daoCreator,
    uint _proposalDeposit,
    uint _minTokensToCreate,
    uint _closingTime,
    address _privateCreation
) TokenCreation(_minTokensToCreate, _closingTime, _privateCreation) {

    curator = _curator;
    daoCreator = _daoCreator;
    proposalDeposit = _proposalDeposit;
    rewardAccount = new ManagedAccount(address(this), false);
    DAOrewardAccount = new ManagedAccount(address(this), false);
    if (address(rewardAccount) == 0)
        throw;
    if (address(DAOrewardAccount) == 0)
        throw;
    lastTimeMinQuorumMet = now;
    minQuorumDivisor = 5; // sets the minimal quorum to 20%
    proposals.length = 1; // avoids a proposal with ID 0 because it is used
    allowedRecipients[address(this)] = true;
    allowedRecipients[curator] = true;
}
```

and is just a blank/zeroed dummy record:

```
["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", // address recipient
"0", // uint amount
"", // string description
"0", // uint votingDeadline
false, // bool open
false, // bool proposalPassed
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", // bytes32 proposalHash
"0", // uint proposalDeposit
false, // bool newCurator
// NO SplitData[] splitData
"0", // uint yea
"0", // uint nay
// NO mapping (address => bool) votedYes
// NO mapping (address => bool) votedNo
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"] // address creator
```

---

#### Checking Out The DAO on Testnet

I ran the following commands that returns the results of some of the proposals on Testnet:

```
> var theDAOAddress="0xad23d7C443382333543Dd13C3B77b99b2A7e2c6D"
undefined
> var theDAOInterfaceABI = [{ "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "proposals", "outputs": [{ "name": "recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "description", "type": "string" }, { "name": "votingDeadline", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "open", "type": "bool" }, { "name": "proposalPassed", "type": "bool" }, { "name": "proposalHash", "type": "bytes32" }, { "name": "proposalDeposit", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "newCurator", "type": "bool" }, { "name": "yea", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "nay", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "creator", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "rewardAccount", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "daoCreator", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_transactionData", "type": "bytes" }], "name": "executeProposal", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "unblockMe", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "totalRewardToken", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "allowedRecipients", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_to", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "transferWithoutReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_description", "type": "string" }, { "name": "_transactionData", "type": "bytes" }, { "name": "_debatingPeriod", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_newCurator", "type": "bool" }], "name": "newProposal", "outputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "DAOpaidOut", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "minQuorumDivisor", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_newContract", "type": "address" }], "name": "newContract", "outputs": [], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_allowed", "type": "bool" }], "name": "changeAllowedRecipients", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "halveMinQuorum", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "paidOut", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_newCurator", "type": "address" }], "name": "splitDAO", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "DAOrewardAccount", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "proposalDeposit", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "numberOfProposals", "outputs": [{ "name": "_numberOfProposals", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "lastTimeMinQuorumMet", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_toMembers", "type": "bool" }], "name": "retrieveDAOReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "receiveEther", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "getNewDAOAddress", "outputs": [{ "name": "_newDAO", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_supportsProposal", "type": "bool" }], "name": "vote", "outputs": [{ "name": "_voteID", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "getMyReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "rewardToken", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_from", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_to", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "transferFromWithoutReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalDeposit", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "changeProposalDeposit", "outputs": [], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "blocked", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "curator", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_transactionData", "type": "bytes" }], "name": "checkProposalCode", "outputs": [{ "name": "_codeChecksOut", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "recipient", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "newCurator", "type": "bool" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "description", "type": "string" }], "name": "ProposalAdded", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "position", "type": "bool" }, { "indexed": true, "name": "voter", "type": "address" }], "name": "Voted", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "result", "type": "bool" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "quorum", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "ProposalTallied", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "_newCurator", "type": "address" }], "name": "NewCurator", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "_allowed", "type": "bool" }], "name": "AllowedRecipientChanged", "type": "event" }];
undefined
> var theDAOInterface = web3.eth.contract(theDAOInterfaceABI).at(theDAOAddress);
undefined
> theDAOInterface.proposals()
["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 0, "", 0, false, false, "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 0, false, 0, 0, "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
> theDAOInterface.proposals(1)
["0x343ca5b0052ea70c6311fdb4bc061c698433d4e3", 0, "test", 1459957706, true, false, "0x9bef2427d88db62a28c0662a9494de97f691ebdd282a6e26cd1caaf2cea5fc41", 0, true, 0, 0, "0x08144824954c65b12f68b75072488e634ac4e67a"]
> theDAOInterface.proposals(2)
["0xd36cd0daab314707cc68300bdb9ba36f098c2784", 0, "test split", 1459958407, true, false, "0x0563d41c2b8a7d3ab5e2118a0fbf9282ab38c3146ec3de19cf86326fa936cd10", 0, true, 0, 0, "0x08144824954c65b12f68b75072488e634ac4e67a"]
> theDAOInterface.proposals(3)
["0xd36cd0daab314707cc68300bdb9ba36f098c2784", 0, "test", 1459959012, true, true, "0x0563d41c2b8a7d3ab5e2118a0fbf9282ab38c3146ec3de19cf86326fa936cd10", 0, true, 1000000000000000000, 0, "0x08144824954c65b12f68b75072488e634ac4e67a"]
```

---

#### Checking Out The First Proposal On Mainnet

**EDIT 29/05/2016 10:31 AEST With First Proposal **

I was looking for [Slock.it's Proposal #1 - DAO.Security (redux)](https://forum.daohub.org/t/slock-it-proposal-1-dao-security-redux/3536/8), and found 5 proposals already created.

Here are the commands and results on Mainnet:

```
> var theDAOAddress="0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413"
undefined
> var theDAOInterfaceABI = [{ "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "proposals", "outputs": [{ "name": "recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "description", "type": "string" }, { "name": "votingDeadline", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "open", "type": "bool" }, { "name": "proposalPassed", "type": "bool" }, { "name": "proposalHash", "type": "bytes32" }, { "name": "proposalDeposit", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "newCurator", "type": "bool" }, { "name": "yea", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "nay", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "creator", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "rewardAccount", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "daoCreator", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_transactionData", "type": "bytes" }], "name": "executeProposal", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "unblockMe", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "totalRewardToken", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "allowedRecipients", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_to", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "transferWithoutReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_description", "type": "string" }, { "name": "_transactionData", "type": "bytes" }, { "name": "_debatingPeriod", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_newCurator", "type": "bool" }], "name": "newProposal", "outputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "DAOpaidOut", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "minQuorumDivisor", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_newContract", "type": "address" }], "name": "newContract", "outputs": [], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_allowed", "type": "bool" }], "name": "changeAllowedRecipients", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "halveMinQuorum", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "paidOut", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_newCurator", "type": "address" }], "name": "splitDAO", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "DAOrewardAccount", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "proposalDeposit", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "numberOfProposals", "outputs": [{ "name": "_numberOfProposals", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "lastTimeMinQuorumMet", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_toMembers", "type": "bool" }], "name": "retrieveDAOReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "receiveEther", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "getNewDAOAddress", "outputs": [{ "name": "_newDAO", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_supportsProposal", "type": "bool" }], "name": "vote", "outputs": [{ "name": "_voteID", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "getMyReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "rewardToken", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_from", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_to", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "transferFromWithoutReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalDeposit", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "changeProposalDeposit", "outputs": [], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "blocked", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "curator", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_transactionData", "type": "bytes" }], "name": "checkProposalCode", "outputs": [{ "name": "_codeChecksOut", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "recipient", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "newCurator", "type": "bool" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "description", "type": "string" }], "name": "ProposalAdded", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "position", "type": "bool" }, { "indexed": true, "name": "voter", "type": "address" }], "name": "Voted", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "result", "type": "bool" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "quorum", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "ProposalTallied", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "_newCurator", "type": "address" }], "name": "NewCurator", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "_allowed", "type": "bool" }], "name": "AllowedRecipientChanged", "type": "event" }];
undefined
> var theDAOInterface = web3.eth.contract(theDAOInterfaceABI).at(theDAOAddress);
undefined
// Following is the dummy proposal
> theDAOInterface.proposals()
["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 0, "", 0, false, false, "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 0, false, 0, 0, "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
// And following is the first proposal
> theDAOInterface.proposals(1)
["0x13680fa2a60fd551894199f009cca20fb63a3e31", 0, "", 1465049035, true, false, "0xf8fc53d03003f6ba1cf65bcbd73238e12045d5c8c92abe6e551cf186bf483ba2", 0, true, 47001968965517241378, 2.536695416315195657391e+21, "0x13680fa2a60fd551894199f009cca20fb63a3e31"]
> theDAOInterface.proposals(2)
["0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413", 0, "Do you believe in god?", 1465665517, true, false, "0x08fc31bd95397edcaa43fbfee1f3552b4d55f8125dea525a959527bb81933141", 2000000000000000000, false, 2.263294834581950253541e+21, 4.722686353944849847392e+21, "0x5a8e70f2d75c1468db4a2241fdd70e5a84f028b8"]
> theDAOInterface.proposals(3)
["0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413", 0, "Should curators only whitelist projects that are related to DAO security for the next 4 weeks?", 1465668580, true, false, "0x08fc31bd95397edcaa43fbfee1f3552b4d55f8125dea525a959527bb81933141", 2000000000000000000, false, 2.30243064182194616977e+21, 6.68352975383731971126e+21, "0x66756ae3ebe94cd4e5e95846fceefcd4f69f8a8d"]
> theDAOInterface.proposals(4)
["0x3d5507b53d1613d8491a606ecf5c9268301095dd", 0, "split", 1465066744, true, false, "0xa4c212a943e73926a115f13aadb145ec1a0c78bda83f72a3f0319a2f9cc78b7b", 0, true, 0, 2.86311518905864295125e+21, "0x3d5507b53d1613d8491a606ecf5c9268301095dd"]
> theDAOInterface.proposals(4)
["0x3d5507b53d1613d8491a606ecf5c9268301095dd", 0, "split", 1465066744, true, false, "0xa4c212a943e73926a115f13aadb145ec1a0c78bda83f72a3f0319a2f9cc78b7b", 0, true, 0, 2.86311518905864295125e+21, "0x3d5507b53d1613d8491a606ecf5c9268301095dd"]
> theDAOInterface.proposals(6)
new BigNumber() not a base 16 number: 
    at raise (web3.js:14426:29)
```

And here is EtherScan.io's [The DAO - Proposals](http://etherscan.io/token/TheDAO#proposals) page.

Comment: what about the items in the proposal array? What do they mean?

Comment: I know the .sol file, I've read the same you did. I mean the array I'm getting, the one full of 0x0000, false, and non-sense fields.

Comment: It is just a dummy record created by the statement `proposals.length = 1` in the `DAO()` constructor.