# Getting TheDAO proposals by code

Tags: contract-invocation, the-dao

I'm using TheDAO Interface to get the proposals like in Etherscan (https://etherscan.io/token/TheDAO#proposals) but I don't get any. My code is like this:

```
var theDAOInterfaceABI = [{ "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "proposals", "outputs": [{ "name": "recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "description", "type": "string" }, { "name": "votingDeadline", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "open", "type": "bool" }, { "name": "proposalPassed", "type": "bool" }, { "name": "proposalHash", "type": "bytes32" }, { "name": "proposalDeposit", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "newCurator", "type": "bool" }, { "name": "yea", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "nay", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "creator", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "rewardAccount", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "daoCreator", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_transactionData", "type": "bytes" }], "name": "executeProposal", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "unblockMe", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "totalRewardToken", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "allowedRecipients", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_to", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "transferWithoutReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_description", "type": "string" }, { "name": "_transactionData", "type": "bytes" }, { "name": "_debatingPeriod", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_newCurator", "type": "bool" }], "name": "newProposal", "outputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "DAOpaidOut", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "minQuorumDivisor", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_newContract", "type": "address" }], "name": "newContract", "outputs": [], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_allowed", "type": "bool" }], "name": "changeAllowedRecipients", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "halveMinQuorum", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "paidOut", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_newCurator", "type": "address" }], "name": "splitDAO", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "DAOrewardAccount", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "proposalDeposit", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "numberOfProposals", "outputs": [{ "name": "_numberOfProposals", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "lastTimeMinQuorumMet", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_toMembers", "type": "bool" }], "name": "retrieveDAOReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "receiveEther", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "getNewDAOAddress", "outputs": [{ "name": "_newDAO", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_supportsProposal", "type": "bool" }], "name": "vote", "outputs": [{ "name": "_voteID", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "getMyReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "_success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "rewardToken", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_from", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_to", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "transferFromWithoutReward", "outputs": [{ "name": "success", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalDeposit", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "changeProposalDeposit", "outputs": [], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "blocked", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "curator", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_transactionData", "type": "bytes" }], "name": "checkProposalCode", "outputs": [{ "name": "_codeChecksOut", "type": "bool" }], "type": "function" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "recipient", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "newCurator", "type": "bool" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "description", "type": "string" }], "name": "ProposalAdded", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "position", "type": "bool" }, { "indexed": true, "name": "voter", "type": "address" }], "name": "Voted", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "proposalID", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "result", "type": "bool" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "quorum", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "ProposalTallied", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "_newCurator", "type": "address" }], "name": "NewCurator", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "_recipient", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "_allowed", "type": "bool" }], "name": "AllowedRecipientChanged", "type": "event" }];
var theDAOAddress = "0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413";
var theDAOInterface = web3.eth.contract(theDAOInterfaceABI).at(theDAOAddress);

console.log(JSON.stringify(theDAOInterface.proposals()));
```

I get:

```
["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0","","0",false,false,"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0",false,"0","0","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As listed in [How can I view The DAO proposals including the current voting status?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-can-i-view-the-dao-proposals-including-the-current-voting-status), you need to add the proposal number to the call `theDAOInterface.proposals(proposalNumber)`. And as discussed in [How to retrieve The DAO proposals using geth?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4320/how-to-retrieve-the-dao-proposals-using-geth), proposal 0 is a dummy proposal.

Code outline below:

```
  var theDAOAddress="0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413";
  var theDAOABI =[{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"proposals","outputs":[{"name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"description","type":"string"},{"name":"votingDeadline","type":"uint256"},{"name":"open","type":"bool"},{"name":"proposalPassed","type":"bool"},{"name":"proposalHash","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"proposalDeposit","type":"uint256"},{"name":"newCurator","type":"bool"},{"name":"yea","type":"uint256"},{"name":"nay","type":"uint256"},{"name":"creator","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"minTokensToCreate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"rewardAccount","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"daoCreator","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"divisor","outputs":[{"name":"divisor","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"extraBalance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_transactionData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"executeProposal","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"unblockMe","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalRewardToken","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"actualBalance","outputs":[{"name":"_actualBalance","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"closingTime","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowedRecipients","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferWithoutReward","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"refund","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_recipient","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_description","type":"string"},{"name":"_transactionData","type":"bytes"},{"name":"_debatingPeriod","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_newCurator","type":"bool"}],"name":"newProposal","outputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"DAOpaidOut","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"minQuorumDivisor","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newContract","type":"address"}],"name":"newContract","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_recipient","type":"address"},{"name":"_allowed","type":"bool"}],"name":"changeAllowedRecipients","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"halveMinQuorum","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"paidOut","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_newCurator","type":"address"}],"name":"splitDAO","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"DAOrewardAccount","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"proposalDeposit","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"numberOfProposals","outputs":[{"name":"_numberOfProposals","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"lastTimeMinQuorumMet","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_toMembers","type":"bool"}],"name":"retrieveDAOReward","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"receiveEther","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"isFueled","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_tokenHolder","type":"address"}],"name":"createTokenProxy","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getNewDAOAddress","outputs":[{"name":"_newDAO","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_supportsProposal","type":"bool"}],"name":"vote","outputs":[{"name":"_voteID","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"getMyReward","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"rewardToken","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFromWithoutReward","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalDeposit","type":"uint256"}],"name":"changeProposalDeposit","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"blocked","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"curator","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_recipient","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_transactionData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"checkProposalCode","outputs":[{"name":"_codeChecksOut","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"privateCreation","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_curator","type":"address"},{"name":"_daoCreator","type":"address"},{"name":"_proposalDeposit","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_minTokensToCreate","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_closingTime","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_privateCreation","type":"address"}],"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"FuelingToDate","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"CreatedToken","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Refund","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"newCurator","type":"bool"},{"indexed":false,"name":"description","type":"string"}],"name":"ProposalAdded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"position","type":"bool"},{"indexed":true,"name":"voter","type":"address"}],"name":"Voted","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"result","type":"bool"},{"indexed":false,"name":"quorum","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ProposalTallied","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_newCurator","type":"address"}],"name":"NewCurator","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_allowed","type":"bool"}],"name":"AllowedRecipientChanged","type":"event"}];
  var theDAO = web3.eth.contract(theDAOABI).at(theDAOAddress);
  var numberOfProposals = theDAO.numberOfProposals();

  var numberOfProposals = theDAO.numberOfProposals();
  for (i = startProposal; i <= endProposal; i++) {
    var proposal = theDAO.proposals(i);  
    var recipient = proposal[0];  
    var amount = proposal[1];
    var description = proposal[2];
    var votingDeadline = proposal[3];
    var open = proposal[4];
    var proposalPassed = proposal[5];
    var yea = proposal[9] / 1e16;
    var yeaPercentOfTotalSupply = yea / totalSupply * 100;
    var nay = proposal[10] / 1e16;
    var nayPercentOfTotalSupply = nay / totalSupply * 100;
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already there, just a step more. You should use:

```
theDAOInterface.proposals(1)
```

to get proposal #1, and so on. Here some helper functions I use:

```
function daoToken(_val){ return Math.floor(_val/10000000000000000); }

function updatedProposalList() {
    var daoProposals = [];
    for(var i = 1; i <= dao.numberOfProposals(); i++) {
        var p = dao.proposals(i);
        daoProposals.push({
            "recipient":p[0],
            "amount":p[1],
            "description":p[2],
            "votingDeadline":p[3],
            "open":p[4],
            "proposalPassed":p[5],
            "proposalHash":p[6],
            "proposalDeposit":p[7],
            "newCurator":p[8],
            "yea":p[9],
            "nay":p[10],
            "creator":p[11]
        });
    }
    return daoProposals;
}

function listProposals() {
    updatedProposalList().forEach( function(val, index) {    
        console.log("#"+ (parseInt(index)+1) +" "+ (val.newCurator?"(SPLIT)":"") +" "+ val.description + " - Yes: " + daoToken(val.yea) +" - No: "+ daoToken(val.nay));
    });
}
```

The current output is:

```
#1 (SPLIT)  - Yes: 789983 - No: 338871
#2  Do you believe in god? - Yes: 723322 - No: 1644386
#3  Should curators only whitelist projects that are related to DAO security for the next 4 weeks? - Yes: 403806 - No: 2624562
#4 (SPLIT) split - Yes: 5279 - No: 418805
#5  Moratorium on proposals until the DAO contract is upgraded (via newContract proposal), fixing most serious issues with voting and splitting. Funds can be moved to the new contract gradually, via multiple proposals. - Yes: 17736492 - No: 920886
#6 (SPLIT) Original intent, non-interventionist curator.  Split to restore nonjudgmental role of curator. - Yes: 1 - No: 91376
#7 (SPLIT) Leave me alone - Yes: 118006 - No: 74938
#8 (SPLIT)  - Yes: 99999 - No: 30833
#9 (SPLIT)  - Yes: 2659799 - No: 30833
#10 (SPLIT)  - Yes: 746 - No: 30833
#11  Curators, please hire somebody to fix the DAO code and allow more recipients - Yes: 387579 - No: 8292378
#12 (SPLIT) ?? cdc00 split proposal ?? - Yes: 81 - No: 20077
#13 (SPLIT) arbitrage ftw - Yes: 0 - No: 77
#14 (SPLIT)  - Yes: 6086 - No: 77
#15  Dear DAO - Tokenholders, I am a simple DAO-Tokenholder and I will not post anything on the conventional Web2.0 social media. At the moment, it seems voting in the DAO has security issues. I am asking all DAO-Tokenholders to show the actual voting-power of the DAO. Please vote YES to show you are actually voting. Please vote NO to show that you are voting but unfortunately, you are a little bit annoyed by that proposal. I am serious. That's why I am willing to spend 2 ETH for this proposal. Lets show what we've got! The DAO is alive! I am auxborg - Yes: 5307863 - No: 748834
```